# How should I handle side-streams in Rx.Net?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I am building a simulation using Rx.Net. User input is modeled as a stream of state transformation on the initial state. Using `Scan` I am able to resolve these transformations into the current state.

The problem is that the transformations may have side-effects. These are modeled as event objects that implement `ISimulationEvent`.

I have tried a few approaches:

- Store the side-effects in the current state object and clear them with each transformation
- Return a `Tuple` of game-states and `IList<ISimulationEvent>` in the `Scan`
- Pass in a side-effect callback to aggregate them

Each solution feels "hacky".

Is there a clean way to implement this using Rx.Net?

---

This is an example of how my commands get folded into states:

```
var commands = mouseStates
    .DistinctUntilChanged(mouseState => mouseState.LeftButton)
    .Where(mouseState => mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    .Select(mouseState => new CreateWidgetCommand(new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y)));

var initialState = new SimulationState();

var states = commands.Scan(
    initialState, 
    (state, command) => command.CanApply(state) ? command.Apply(state) : state);
```

Each `Apply` should output a stream of `ISimulationEvent` as a side-effect. However, I also need to keep the resultant `SimulationState`.

Comment: It would be very useful if you provide a code sample

Comment: So you mean state transformations can have side effects that affect not just the current state, but other parts of the program? Looks like you want to move those into the current state too.

Comment: Oh so that is the first option you mentioned. Why would you clear those side effects? wouldnt it be easier to just not have those side effects?

Comment: Nevermind, I still don't understand what is the problem exactly. Some more information would be appreciated.

Comment: If a certain state transition happens (maybe there is a collision, for example) I would like a side-effect (a sound effect, for example). Ideally,  these side-effects would be a stream. It is complicated by the fact that they are generated by transitions in a `Scan`.

Comment: It would be great to get a [mcve], or, in other words, working example code.

Comment: I have added some code to illustrate the problem better.